# Laravel 5.0 configuration file mail.php not loaded

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, laravel-5

I have a problem with the configuration in Laravel 5.0

I configured an environment `local` from an `.env` file. The machine is a homestead machine and i removed the `APP_ENV` from the `Homestead.yaml` just to be sure.

Environment is set to local and i confirmed by prompting `$app->environment()`

I added a few configuration files to the local config directory (local/filesystems.php, local/mail.php, local/services.php). The interesting thing is the filesystems.php gets loaded but the mail one not. If i dump the `getConfigurationFiles()` from `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration` i get

```
array:11 [▼
  "app" => "/home/vagrant/Code/molkerei/config/app.php"
  "auth" => "/home/vagrant/Code/molkerei/config/auth.php"
  "cache" => "/home/vagrant/Code/molkerei/config/cache.php"
  "compile" => "/home/vagrant/Code/molkerei/config/compile.php"
  "database" => "/home/vagrant/Code/molkerei/config/database.php"
  "filesystems" => "/home/vagrant/Code/molkerei/config/local/filesystems.php"
  "mail" => "/home/vagrant/Code/molkerei/config/mail.php"
  "services" => "/home/vagrant/Code/molkerei/config/services.php"
  "queue" => "/home/vagrant/Code/molkerei/config/queue.php"
  "session" => "/home/vagrant/Code/molkerei/config/session.php"
  "view" => "/home/vagrant/Code/molkerei/config/view.php"
]
```

I already tried to clean the cache with `php artisan cache:clear` but there is not even a cache file (it is set to filesystem)

Any idea why the configuration is not loaded properly?

Comment: Laravel 5 is not a stable release yet so you may find you'll be hard-pressed for an answer on here. You can always use 4.2 for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer - there are no more 'sub directories' for config like there used to be in L4 - You now have one main configuration folder.

You overwrite any default config with specific config from your '.env' file if required.

So in your `app\config\mail.php` file you would write:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mandrill'),
```

Which means it will use Mandrill by default - unless in your `.env` file you put

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
```

which means on your homestead server it will now use SMTP to send the mail.

p.s. I do not know why filesystems loads the `local` config in your example - it is probably a bug.

Comment: okay, i got it, maybe i would have figured that out if filesystems was not loaded (i saw no sub directory loading in the code, but somehow this directory was loaded). I think the .env file is an improvement although i think switching config quickly was easier before. Thanks